# Cannot access empty property error

Tags: php

I'm working on an advanced search but got error

> Fatal error: Cannot access empty property `*$this->$Personnummer*`

Here is my controller:

```
<?php
include 'c:/wamp/www/mvc/model/SearchProcessor.php';
// if the user clicks the submit button, it sends its name values here and if not empty, binds them to $data.
        if(isset($_POST['button'])) {

                if($_POST['name'] !='');
                {
                        $data['name'] = $_POST['name'];
                }

                if($_POST['lastname'] !='');
                {
                        $data['lastname'] = $_POST['lastname'];
                }


                if($_POST['Personnummer_search'] !='');
                {
                        $data['Personnummer'] = $_POST['Personnummer_search'];
                }

                if($_POST['Kon_search'] !='');
                {
                        $data['Kon_search'] = $_POST['Kon_search'];
                }

                if($_POST['Anvands_search'] !='');
                {
                        $data['Anvands_search'] = $_POST['Anvands_search'];
                }

                if($_POST['Lan_search'] !='');
                {
                        $data['Lan_search'] = $_POST['Lan_search'];
                }

                if($_POST['Processormodell_search'] !='');
                {
                        $data['Processormodell_search'] = $_POST['Processormodell_search'];
                }

                if($_POST['Sida_search'] !='');
                {
                        $data['Sida_search'] = $_POST['Sida_search'];
                }

                if($_POST['utlamnat_search'] !='');
                {
                        $data['utlamnat_search'] = $_POST['utlamnat_search'];
                }

                if($_POST['ProcessorSerie_search'] !='');
                {
                        $data['ProcessorSerie_search'] = $_POST['ProcessorSerie_search'];
                }

                if($_POST['Tillverkare_search'] !='');
                {
                        $data['Tillverkare_search'] = $_POST['Tillverkare_search'];
                }


                $displayResults = new SearchProcessor($db,$data);
                $Results = $displayResults->getSearchResult();
```

Here is the model:

```
<?php
require_once 'Database.php';
//This class is for searching for patient and their processors
class SearchProcessor extends Database {
    private $Personnummer;
    private $TheKon;
    private $TheLan;
    private $name;
    private $TheLastname;
    private $TheProcessor;
    private $TheAnvands;
    private $TheSida;
    private $TheUtlamnat;
    private $TheSerienummer;
    private $TheTillverkare;

    //The constructor of both the parent and child class
    function __construct(mysqli $db, $data)
    {
        parent::__construct($db);
        //set data
        $this->setData($data);
        // get search result
        $this->getSearchResult();
    }
    //Sets the data
    function setData($data)
    {
        $this->name = $data['name'];
        $this->TheLastname = $data['lastname'];
        $this->Personnummer = $data['Personnummer'];
        $this->TheKon = $data['Kon_search'];
        $this->TheAnvands = $data['Anvands_search'];
        $this->TheLan = $data['Lan_search'];
        $this->TheProcessor = $data['Processormodell_search'];
        $this->TheSida =$data['Sida_search'];
        $this->TheUtlamnat =$data['utlamnat_search'];
        $this->TheSerienummer = $data['ProcessorSerie_search'];
        $this->TheTillverkare = $data['Tillverkare_search'];

    }


//This function searches each column regarding patient and its processors.
    function getSearchResult() {

        $where = array();
            $where[] =  "Patient.Patient LIKE '%".$this->$Personnummer."%'"; //<--- ERROR  Cannot access empty property 
            $where[] =  "person.Namn LIKE '%".$this->name."%'";
            $where[] =  "person.Efternamn LIKE '%".$this->TheLastname."%'";
            $where[] =  "person.Kon LIKE '%".$this->TheKon."%'";
            $where[] =  "processorpatient.Sida LIKE '%".$this->TheSida."%'";
            $where[] =  "person.Lan LIKE '%".$this->TheLan."%'";
            $where[] =  "processorpatient.Tillverkare LIKE '%".$this->TheTillverkare."%'";
            $where[] =  "processorpatient.Processor LIKE '%".$this->TheProcessor."%'";
            $where[] =  "processorpatient.Utlamnat LIKE '%".$this->TheUtlamnat."%'";
            $where[] =  "processorpatient.Anvands LIKE '%".$this->TheAnvands."%'";
            $where[] =  "processorpatient.Serienummer LIKE '%".$this->TheSerienummer."%'";

        if(count($where)) // here it counts the amount of $where and a extends the query to search deeper into the database.
        {

            $Data = array();
            $sql = "Select * from patient left join person on person.Personnummer = patient.Patient left join processorpatient on processorpatient.patientv = patient.Patient
     WHERE ".implode(" AND ",$where);
            if(!$result = $this->mysqli->query($sql)) {
                throw new exception("Error: Can not execute the query.");
            } else {
                $Count = $result->num_rows;
                if($Count>0)
                {
                    for($i=0; $i<$Count; $i++)
                    {
                        $Data[$i] = $result->fetch_assoc();
                    }
                }
            }
            return $Data;
    }

    }

}
```

What I want to be doing is assign user input $_POST[''] to variables $data[''] in the controller. And then pass it the model class that is supposed to bind it with their own private variables in which is giving value to the query. But I'm getting error *Cannot access empty property* `$this->$Personnummer` at the model

Comment: would be $this->Personnummer

Comment: The variable $Personnummer doesn't exist, so it's a blank property name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

access variable without `$` as like same as you defined above

```
$this->Personnummer = $data['Personnummer'];
```

so access this like

```
$where[] =  "Patient.Patient LIKE '%".$this->Personnummer."%'";
```

Comment: Thank you very much it sure solved that problem. However somehow the variable `$this->personnummer` is not the input from the user, I've looked over the connections between `$_POST['Personummer_Search']` and `$data['personummer']` but can't find what's wrong